# Multidimensional Quadratic Equation into Matrix Representation

Tags: programming, polynomials

How does one transform the following multidimensional quadratic equation into matrix form in Mathematica:

$f(x,y,z)=a x^2+b y^2+c z^2+d xy+e yz+p y+q z+r$,

where, $a,b,c,d,e,p,q$ and $r$ are real numbers.

I want to write this in the following form:

$f(x,y,z)=\textbf{x}^TM\textbf{x}+n^T\textbf{x}+o$,

where $M$ is a 3x3 matrix, $n$ is a vector and $o$ is some constant (real), and of course $\textbf{x}=\{x,y,z\}$, a vector containing my variables. I am struggling with my Mathematica script to accomplish this task. Anybody got a smart idea to program this in Mathematica?

I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: please include the mathematica code you've tried thusfar.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want `CoefficientArrays[]` with the `"Symmetric" -> True` setting for this:

```
quad = a x^2 + b y^2 + c z^2 + d x y + e y z + p y + q z + r; vars = {x, y, z};
{o, n, m} = Normal @ CoefficientArrays[quad, vars, "Symmetric" -> True];
vars.m.vars + n.vars + o == quad // Simplify
   True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f[x_, y_, z_] = a x^2 + b y^2 + c z^2  + d x y + e y z + p y + q z + r;
matA = 1/2 Map[D[#, {{x, y, z}}] &, 
 Map[D[#, {{x, y, z}}] &, f[x, y, z]]] /. Map[# -> 0 &, {x, y, z}];
vecb = Map[D[#, {{x, y, z}}] &, f[x, y, z]] /. 
Map[# -> 0 &, {x, y, z}];
s = f[x, y, z] /. Map[# -> 0 &, {x, y, z}];
Simplify[f[x, y, z] - {x, y, z}.matA.{x, y, z} - vecb.{x, y, z} - s]
```